# What can I do to optimise this code?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, infrared

I have optimised it as much as I feel I can and want to know what suggestions you have that could make it more efficient etc.

Note: I know the array goes on forever :)

```
volatile uint16_t IRCode[]={340,171,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,1556,340,86,21,3654}; // ProntoHex to uint16_t delete first 4 array numbers.
volatile uint16_t MicrosPassed;
volatile uint8_t Array_Seq;
uint8_t State;

void setup() {
  Config(); // Config sketch will set working settings for different microcontrollers.
  SendIRCode();
}

void loop() {

}

void SendIRCode() {
  switch(State) {
    case 1:
      TCCR1A&=63; // Opposite of case 0 -193 = 63
      State=0;
      break;

    case 0:
      TCCR1A|=192;
      State=1;
      break;
  }
}

void Config() {
  DDRB|=10;
  ICR1=416;
  OCR1A=9983;
  TCCR1A=2;
  TCCR1B=24;
  TCCR1B|=1;
  TIMSK1=1;
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  MicrosPassed++;
  if(MicrosPassed==IRCode[Array_Seq]) {
    SendIRCode();
    MicrosPassed=0;
    Array_Seq++;
       }
}
```

Comment: IRCode[], MicrosPassed, and Array_Seq are only used in the ISR; you could declare them as static in the ISR, IRCode[] could also be const, and no need to declare them as volatile because only the ISR reads/writes them. No idea if this will help the compiler optimising for speed, though.

Comment: For what to do you want to optimize? Clean code? Or some meaning of "speed" (which speed)?

Comment: convert array to actual bits .. `0` is 21, 21 ... `1` is 21, 64 ... `s` is  340, 17 - start ... and so on .... the array would be { s, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ......} ... you could even store bytes, instead of separate bits

Comment: Maybe fix the problem @chrisl [mentioned](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78973/infrared-low-frequency-transmission#comment175438_78973) before optimizing your code.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by chrisl in a comment, there are various criteria you may
want to optimize for: speed, size, readability... Judging from the
current state of this sketch, I would say that your first goal at this
point should be to optimize for readability.

The hardest think to make sense of are most of the plain numbers. When
setting registers that are bit fields, do not use decimal values: use
either hexadecimal or binary. Or, better yet, use the names of the bits.
The avr-libc defines those names, as well as the macro
`_BV(bit_position)`, which expands to `(1 << bit_position)` and is meant
to be used with those names:

```cpp
void Config() {
  DDRB   |= _BV(PB1) | _BV(PB3);  // PB1 and PB3 as output
  ICR1    =  416;        // timer period = 417 cycles
  OCR1A   = 9983;        // ???
  TCCR1A  = _BV(WGM11);  // mode 14: fast PWM, TOP = ICR1
  TCCR1B  = _BV(WGM12) | _BV(WGM13);  // ...ditto
  TCCR1B |= _BV(CS10);   // clock @ F_CPU
  TIMSK1  = _BV(TOIE1);  // enable TIMER1_OVF interrupt
}
```

Granted, the bit names are somewhat obscure, but they do make the
program easier to read if you have the datasheet nearby. I do like to
have comments that make the code understandable even without reading the
datasheet.

Note that evaluating those expressions does not make the program any
slower, as they are evaluated at compile time.

When a variable is used in a single function, it is better to define it
in that function. Keeping the definition close to where the variable is
used makes the code more “local” and thus easier to read. Since you want
some of those variables to remember their values across invocations of
the function, give them the `static` qualifier.

You may not need to optimize this program for speed. There is, however,
a low hanging fruit here: remove the `volatile` keywords. This keyword
is meant to explicitly *disable* some compiler optimizations that are
unsafe when a variable is shared between the interrupt and non-interrupt
contexts. None of the variable you use needs this.

If I understood correctly, the function `SendIRCode()` just toggles a
couple of bits in `TCCR1A`. You can simplify it to this:

```cpp
void SendIRCode() {
  TCCR1A ^= _BV(COM1A0) | _BV(COM1A1);  // toggle PWM output on OC1A
}
```

Finally, there is I believe a bug in this sketch. The variable
`Array_Seq` is continuously incremented and never reset. The program
will then end up reading past the end of the `IRCode` array.